# How can I duplicate a surface inside the graphics card memory?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-9

I want to duplicate a surface in graphic card memory (Is it called Video Memory?), this is how I get a back buffer surface:

```
HRESULT hRes = m_pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, 
    IREF_GETPPTR(pBackBuffer,IDirect3DSurface9));
```

Then I lock it(code was omitted here) , and copy the data in the back buffer surface like this:

```
    IRefPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> pSurfTemp;
hRes = m_pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
    g_Proc.m_Stats.m_SizeWnd.cx, g_Proc.m_Stats.m_SizeWnd.cy, 
    s_bbFormat, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, 
    IREF_GETPPTR(pSurfTemp,IDirect3DSurface9), NULL );
hRes = m_pDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pBackBuffer, pSurfTemp);
```

Is the back buffer surface data I got in the first code block in Video Memory?
A parameter in CreateOffscreenPlainSurface is D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM. Can I duplicate the surface inside video memory by change this parameter into D3DPOOL_SCRATCH or something?

Comment: Why do you duplicate it?

Comment: @zdd I want to capture a game video. I have already hooked successfully and I can get back buffer from the game I hooked. When I copy a buffer out, I need to lock the buffer until copying done. Since I need to lock back buffer and wait for copying, the FPS of the game will decrease. I guess the copy method I am using now is to transform data from video memory into CPU. If so, since I use hardware codec, the data need to be copy back to video memory to encode. That waste a lot of time.

Comment: @zdd If I duplicate the surface inside the video memory, 1)it is faster than copy it out into CPU, decrease waiting time, and will increase FPS 2)Need not copy it from CPU back to Video card

Comment: If you want to capture the game video, i think you should use GetFrontBufferData instead of the back buffer, but this method is very slow.

Comment: did you render anyting? or just capturing?

Comment: @zdd why frontbuffer? I can capture and codec video use back buffer now. Point is , I need to improve the performance. I hooked the prensent function. I draw a hooking indicator on the left top of the game.

Comment: sorry for missing the word "hook" in your comments above, If you didn't use hooking, you will get nothing by GetRenderTargetData since you didn't render anyting. but you use it!

Comment: @zdd I found a method D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface, Is it useful?